# Inaugurativus or inauguralis?

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, derivation

What would be a good Latin adjective for things related to opening ceremonies?
It might be used together with words meaning speech, ceremony, parade or something similar.
Starting with the verb *inaugurare*, the derivatives *inaugurativus* and *inauguralis* come to mind.
I have used *inaugurativus*.
Which one is better?
Or is there perhaps a better adjective than either of these?
Do *inaugurativus* and *inauguralis* mean the same if they are both usable?

Answer (score 3):

Google gives quite a lot of hits for [*inauguralis*](https://www.google.com/search?q=inauguralis&oq=inauguralis&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (in phrases like *dissertatio inauguralis, lectio inauguralis*), and very few for [*inaugurativus*](https://www.google.com/search?q=inaugurativus&oq=inaugurativus&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=inaugurativus&nfpr=1), most of which aren't actually Latin. So I'd say that's your answer. (For what it's worth, *inauguralis* sounds better to me personally.)

Comment: Can you include some references to corroborate this?

Comment: @brianpck I added links to the Google searches.